# git ls-files run from subdirectory

Tags: git, unix, gitignore, git-ls-files

I'm trying to make a shell.sh that when run with bash will basically just run command: `git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard`

which works perfectly when run from base repo directory, but when i change current directory to *repo/folder and run it from there, there is no output.

```
so: \
 *repo/git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard -- good \
 *repo/folder/git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard -- no bueno
```

does anyone know why it does this and how to remediate? Thanks

Comment: `git ls-files` only lists the files tracked by git. Are you in a `folder` that is ignored (`.gitignore`), contains only ignored files, or does not contain any files at all? Note that `--exclude-standard` still won't cause it to include untracked files.

Comment: .gitignore is in the repo folder, but i need to run it from repo/folder

Answer (score 2):

Running `git ls-files` is a little like running `ls -R` -- it only considers files in the current directory or below. It's producing no output because (presumably) the only files matching your criteria existing only at the top level of the repository.

It sounds like you always want to run `git ls-files` from the top directory, regardless of your current location. You can do that like this:

```
git -C $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard
```